# Finding a pair of numbers in a list that sums to a target number

Tags: python, list, sum

The assignment I'm working on specifies to write a function called `sum_pairs` which accepts a list and a number and returns the first pair of numbers that sum to the number passed.

This is the desires result:

```
sum_pairs([4,2,10,5,1], 6) # [4,2]
```

The only way I could think of completing this is using the random module:

```
def sum_pairs(lst, num):
    rand_num_one = choice(lst)
    rand_num_two = choice(lst)
    if rand_num_one + rand_num_two == num:
        x = [rand_num_one, rand_num_two]
        return x
```

However, I know there's another way to do this without having to use the random module. I just can't put my finger on it. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That potentially gives you the wrong answer because it can pick the same number twice. Why not loop over the list, then have an inner loop over the rest of the list?

Comment: "returns the **first** pair" and "random" don't really get together ...

Comment: Does it have to be a consecutive pair? What if your list is `[4, 5 2]`?

Comment: are the numbers distinct?

Comment: I updated by answer so now there is a solution with `random`, but it doens't return the 'first pair'

Comment: why don't you use `itertools.combinations` ? and return the first pair that matches the sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why do you use `random`? you need to return the first sum

```py
def sum_pairs(lst, num):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(lst)):
            if lst[i] + lst[j] == num:
                return lst[i],lst[j]
```

## Update

If you want to use the `random` module, you can do this:

```py
def sum_pairs(lst, num):
    first = choice(lst)
    temp = lst[::]
    temp.remove(first)
    second = choice(temp)
    while first + second != num:
        first = choice(lst)
        temp = lst[::]
        temp.remove(first)
        second = choice(temp)
    return first,second
```

but this doesn't really the answer to your question

Comment: @kaceywills what result?

Comment: sorry this is my first time using stack overflow so i'm trying to get used to the forums

Comment: im still not understanding the way i interpret your new code is like this: for i in range(5):
   for j in range(0, 5):
       if lst[0] + lst[0] == num
    return lst[0], lst[0]

Comment: if my lst = [4,2,10,5,1] and my num==6, the way i interpret it is that code will just keep adding the same index for example 4 + 4, 2 + 4, etc....

Comment: @kaceywills check that the second `range` start from i, and not from 0 :)

Comment: @kaceywills also if you find this answer as the correct one mark it as the correct one so it will help other peoples :)

Comment: i is == to 0 through the first iteration though isn't it? The way i learned about range is if you just have a start value such as for i in range(5) the first time through that iteration i is going to be 0 and the last time its going to be 4 to gives 5 elements total.

Comment: @kaceywills oh yes, sorry, i fixed it :)

Comment: how do i pin your answer to the top/ mark it as correct?

Comment: @kaceywills no problem :) there is a green V sign under the vote count of the answer :)

Comment: side note: this is `O(n²)` for  time complexity, there is a `O(n)` solution (drawback is `O(n)` space complexity vs `O(1)` for this solution)

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completness, here is a solution with `O(n)` for time complexity:

```
def find_pair(values, total):
  known = set()
  for value in values:
    if total - value in known:
      return value, total - value
    known.add(value)
```

Comment: Using a set would not work for `sum_pairs([4,2,10,5,1], 10)`, which would incorrectly return `(5, 5)` when there is no such pair in the list, which is why you'd have to use a `Counter` instead.

Comment: it doesn't return `(5, 5)`, unless there is _already_ a `5` in the set when the second `5` is encountered. See how the set is built of elements already visited (this is a simplification over the method where you keep the index in a dict in case you need to return the indices instead of the values). See for yourself: https://repl.it/repls/MobileQuickFlashdrives

Comment: True. I misunderstood your approach. It does work then. +1

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient method that takes only *O(n)* in time complexity would be to use `collections.Counter` to create a counter dict for the given list, so that you can iterate over the keys and check if the number that will add up with the current number to the target number has a counter greater than 0, or if that number is the same as the current number, greater than 1, at which point you can output both the current number and its counterpart:

```
from collections import Counter
def sum_pairs(lst, target):
    counts = Counter(lst)
    return next(
        [num, target - num] for num in counts
        if counts.get(target - num, 0) > (target - num == num)
    )
```

so that:

```
sum_pairs([4,2,10,5,1], 6)
```

returns:

```
[4, 2]
```

Comment: I think `counts - Counter([num])`  iterates on the counter as well, making this whole thing n², although I'm not entirely sure, as it could only iterate on the smallest counter

Comment: No it does not. `Counter([num])` takes constant time to instantiate the object from one item. And the subtraction of one single item from a `Counter` object takes constant time because it takes *O(1)* to look up the key.

Comment: but the time complexity of creating a new counter (which the `-` operator does) surely is linear to the size of the counter (in this case, n), isn't it?

Comment: True. I've updated my answer to avoid using subtraction then. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In order to iterate through all possible pairs (without repetitions) you can use `itertools.combinations(p,r)`:

```py
import itertools

def sum_pairs(lst, total_sum):
    for el in itertools.combinations(lst, 2):
        if(sum(el)==total_sum):
            return el
    return None

print(sum_pairs([4,2,10,5,1], 6))
print(sum_pairs([4,2,10,5,1], 16))
print(sum_pairs([4,2,10,5,1], 3))
print(sum_pairs([4,2,10,5,1], 2))
```

Output:

```py
(4, 2)
None                                                        
(2, 1)                                                      
None                                                        
[Program finished]
```